# How to force UWP function binding to re-evaluate

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I've been reading on the [UWP documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings#path-to-the-function) that it's possible to bind to a function and have the function re-evaluate via PropertyChanged event.  Actually, I was able to successfully create a sample project that behaves exactly as I want it to, but when I try to implement this feature in my existing project, I don't have the same luck.  Here's what's happening when I invoke a property changed event:

-The changed properties are updated (as expected)

-The function calls that pass changed properties are re-evaluated (as expected)

-Other functions are re-evaluated in test project (as expected) but are not re-evaluated in my existing project (contrary to expectations)

For example, with MyViewModel set like this:

```
class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
    public string MyMethod(string str) => DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

(where `BaseViewModel` is a class that includes a `RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)` method)

And my view set to include this:

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBlock Name="txb1" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyProp,Mode=OneWay}" />
   <TextBlock Name="txb2" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyMethod(ViewModel.MyProp),Mode=OneWay}" />
   <TextBlock Name="txb3" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyMethod('some string'),Mode=OneWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

(where `ViewModel` is an instance of `MyViewModel`)

Then calling `RaisePropertyChanged('MyProp')` will cause `txb1` and `txb2` to update as expected in either project, but calling `RaisePropertyChanged('MyMethod')` causes `txb2` and `txb3` to be re-evaluated in my sample project, while nothing happens in my existing project.

I've remembered to check:

-The spelling of `MyMethod` when I call `RaisePropertyChanged('MyMethod')`

-That my bindings include `Mode=OneWay` and not `Mode=OneTime`

I've  also been trying to check spelling in my XAML, but the fact that everything compiles makes me feel like that's not where the issue is (I can't be compile binding to a non-existent method).

As a workaround, I intend to pass an unneeded property to MyMethod, but I would really like to know if anyone has any idea what else might be changing between projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but calling RaisePropertyChanged('MyMethod') causes txb2 and txb3 to be re-evaluated in my sample project, while nothing happens in my existing project.

Your code could works well in my side when RaisePropertyChanged for MyMethod function. And I used [`CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/) `ObservableObject` as father class for viewmodel and make a command to invoke OnPropertyChanged manually. For more info please refer to official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings#path-to-the-function).

```
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private string _myProp;
    public string MyProp
    {
        get => _myProp;
        set => SetProperty(ref _myProp, value);
    }
    public string MyMethod(string str) => DateTime.Now.ToString();

    public RelayCommand UpdateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyMethod));
              //  MyProp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, but I find the suggestion to use `ObservableObject` and the `nameof` expression very helpful.  Since this is the best answer, I'm marking it.  If I find what the problem is I'll post the solution.  There's obviously something else I'm doing on the page that's throwing off the re-evaluation, but I don't know what it could be.

Comment: Ok, if you have any updates please go ahead comment below.